# Defining a reverse proxy with multiple domains and SSL certificates?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm setting a reverse proxy with nginx to expose several web apps that I run on local machines in the home network to the internet. I have it working and now I'm trying to add SSL support. The nginx instance is accessible via `http://server.local` from the home network and `http://home.mydomain.com` from outside. I'm using docker compose for the setup of nginx and the certbot renewal task in case that matters. I have a certbot certificate (will be auto-renewed) for the external domain, and a self-signed one for the local one.

I can't set up nginx to serve different certificates for different domains unless cloning the `server` directive twice (which I don't want to do as it contains quite a few `locations` with some config in them for all the proxied servers).

My nginx config generally looks like this:

```
http { 
  server { 
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name home.mydomain.com server.local;
    ssl_certificate $certfile;   # set before in a map directive from $host to the cert file.
    ssl_certificate_key $keyfile;   # ditto.
    
    location /site1/ { ... }
    location /site2/ { ... } 
    ...
}
```

When I'm using `map` or the `$host` directly in the certificate filename, it causes nginx to load the privkey.pem file by the worker process (runs as nginx) rather than the master process (runs as root) so it fails to read the privkey.pem file that certbot generates. It's documented that nginx should use the master process to read the private key, but I guess that doesn't happen with dynamic mappings. While I can chmod the files I obviously don't want to do so as certbot's approach of keeping the private key accessible by root only seems more reasonable. Also - even if I chmod these files, renewed certificates will still have the same problem.

If I want to keep the file paths static (so they can be preloaded), the only way I see is to duplicate the server directive. I would be perfectly fine with this if it only contained the ports, ssl and server_name parts, but having to duplicate all locations seems really bad.

Am I missing something here?  Is there a way to make nginx read the private keys in advance? Or can I define locations outside of the servers and then "include" them or something similar?

Thanks!

Comment: The `server` block encapsulates the domain name and its certificate. So you have no choice but to duplicate. You can simplify each `server` block by including duplicated content from a separate file.